# How does Gunicorn work on a server hosting several Flask sites?

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

--I'm deploying several Flask-based sites on a Linode VPS using NGINX as the static server/reverse-proxy.

--I fully understand how that works for multiple sites by reading the incoming header and using the /etc/nginx .conf files for each given site.

--What I'm having trouble finding clarity on is how the gunicorn installed in *each* site's venv is started-up to handle the WSGI calls sent from the VPS-wide NGINX server.

--I see supervisord used in tutorials but only with regard to a single site and not how supervisord running at the VPS level (like NGINX) can start-up Gunicorn for a particular site. It also isn't clear to me why each site has its own installation of Gunicorn. How does this work?

Sorry if this duplicates other questions, but I'm not finding any answers here or elsewhere.

Comment: Is your question? "How to launch two different sites(site1.com running at [127.0.0.1:8000], site2.com running at [127.0.0.1:8001]) under a single server instance?"

Comment: Not exactly, but I take it you're hinting I should run a single global (VPS-wide) instance of gunicorn (with an appropriate number of workers) and use a different 8xxx port for each site I want to host. I guess I do that in the wsgi code for each app, and use supervisord to make sure the single gunicorn instance stays running. Is that correct? If so, what is the reason for installing the gunicorn binaries in each site's venv?

Comment: Gunicorn binaries are recommended(however not enforced) to be installed per venv in order to maintain segregation between site specific configurations (/etc/gunicorn.d), log location staying separate(/var/log/gunicorn) and user/group specific control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGINX should redirect traffic to the appropriate ports. Each flask site needs it's own gunicorn workers started up for it.

So for example, your run commands for each of your sites in the supervisor config would look something like this:

```
[program:site1]
command=venv1/bin/gunicorn --workers num_workers --bind localhost:8081 flask_app1:app
#etc...

[program:site2]
command=venv2/bin/gunicorn --workers num_workers --bind localhost:8082 flask_app2:app
#etc...
```

Hopefully this adds some clarity

EDIT:

Here's a sample NGINX config for one of the sites listening on http.

```
#Config Contents
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  site.your.domain;
    # Or use the following if you do not have a domain
    #server_name 123.123.123.123;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! That helps to clarify a great deal. Do you recommend calling the app directly or through a wsgi.py file? Also, can you confirm I set the upstream-server to port 80xx in the "/etc/nginx/sites-available/site_x.conf" file for that site? Lastly, how many instances of gunicorn can run on a server (2GB w/4 virtual cores) simultaneously? Thanks again!

Comment: Calling through a wsgi file is nice because it allows you to set configuration without gunicorn command line arguments. The port which NGINX is reverse proxying to should match the port you set as the binding port for that site. Quoting the Gunicorn read the docs " Generally we recommend (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers to start off with."

Comment: Thanks again, Brannon. Your last additions cleared up all my questions!